# HTML5 validation and multiple forms

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML5 page with 4 tabs that when a tab is clicked, I am using jQuery, it will show a div containing a form, and hide the other div and forms obviously if they are currently showing.

I am getting a problem with Html5 validation, the validation seems to include all the forms in the validation check, the forms have unique id's 'cqt-form-1', 'cqt-form-2', 'cqt-form-3' and 'cqt-form-4'.

what is going on? I want the only visible/active form to be validated and submitted.

I have also used unique id within form, i.e. area-1-name, area-2-name ect... but leaving the names the same name='name' in each form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What's going on? You tell us. :-) You haven't said what the "problem" is.

Comment: Can you post your code?